# Fallo de conexión con el LDAP

Tags: ubuntu, server, ldap

Tengo un problema al configurar un Ubuntu server. Instalo el LDAP con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt install slapd && sudo apt install ldap-utils
```

Me dice que todo correcto y lo instala, pero cuando configuro me sale

> `can't Contact LDAP server (-1) error ldap`

No entiendo por qué me sale este error ya que instalé con éxito el LDAP.

Probé a actualizar los paquetes luego de instalar el LDAP y aun así sigue saliendo el mismo error.